# MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not calling registerForActivityResult

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, startactivityforresult

I'm upgrading the app to target android 12, before its targeting android 10. So, now I'm using `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` with `registerForActivityResult` but when user **allow access to manage files** and press back button the `registerForActivityResult` do not get called. Here is my code.
In `onCreate` method

```
    registerLauncher();
    if (checkPermissionsGranted()) {
        initMainActivity();
    } else {
        requestPermission();
    }
```

The above methods in sequence.

```
private void registerLauncher() {
        permissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "inside activity result");
                            initMainActivity();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

private boolean checkPermissionsGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            return Environment.isExternalStorageManager();
        } else {
            int readPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int writePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
//            int storagePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission_group.STORAGE);
            return readPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && writePermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            try {
//                Uri uri = Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
//                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, uri);
//                startActivity(intent);
//                permissionLauncher.launch(intent);
//                startActivityForResult(intent, AppConstants.STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
             //   startActivityForResult(intent, AppConstants.STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
                permissionLauncher.launch(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exp... " + e.toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                permissionLauncher.launch(intent);
            }
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Splashscreen.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission_group.STORAGE}, AppConstants.STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }
    }
```

I also tried with `startActivityForResult(intent, AppConstants.STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);` (I know `startActivityForResult` is deprecated) with overriding `onRequestPermissionsResult` but none of these two get called
1 - registerForActivityResult
2 - onRequestPermissionsResult

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here? As I'm check the permission on splash activity, the app get stuck on the splash as onResult is not being called.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Neither of those `Intent` actions return a result, so you should never receive `RESULT_OK`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Oh, thanks for your response. I get it

Comment: But I have seen some of the posts on SO that use `startActivityForResult` along with `onRequestPermissionsResult`. How they get it to work? just curious

Comment: "How they get it to work?" -- that combination does not make sense, sorry. `requestPermissions()` goese with `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, and those are for more conventional types of permissions (e.g., `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`).

Comment: thanks for the clarification

Comment: So the question remains, how it will work, I mean which approach is good for Android 11/12?

Answer (score 0):

after checking the permission on splash activity, you have two options back to the App. either click on back button on the top left corner or click on app icon. but you will be get never Activity.RESULT_OK as result. Therefore, you should handle it differently by querying Environment.isExternalStorageManager().

change your registerLauncher() function as bellow.

```
private void registerLauncher() {
    permissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "inside activity result");
                        initMainActivity();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```